# Getting rid of additional space above and below the title of a part

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, sectioning, parts, scrbook

I am writing lecture notes in LaTeX, and I want to follow some formatting guidelines set forth in the Corporate Design Guide of the university that I'm attending. In particular, I want to set up my title page and the pages inserted at the beginning of each *part* in a very specific way. To do so, I'm using TikZ and the TikZ library `calc` to correctly position individual parts on these pages.

Here's the problem I'm facing: The positioning of what I have labeled `% TEXTBOX` in the MWE below is relative to the top/bottom of what I have labeled `% (SUB-)HEADLINE` in the MWE. On my title page, this works perfectly fine. By that, I mean that the box that encloses the text in the `% (SUB-)HEADLINE` components starts and ends directly above and below the actual text. However, for the pages introduced by the `\part{...}` command at the beginning of each part, there seems to be additional space above and below the text in the `% HEADLINE` part of the page. This amount of space changes as I manipulate the second argument of the `\fontsize{}{}` command, and the behavior is different depending on whether the part title spans one line or two lines (as shown in the MWE). Note that, the values chosen in the `\fontsize` command are not arbitrary, but are fixed in the style guideline I intend to follow. Hence, I would rather not change these, if possible.

I have spent quite a bit of time trying to find an answer to this problem and have come across the following commands:

- `partheadstartvskip`
- `partheadendvskip`
- `RedeclareSectionCommand[...]{part}` along with the options/parameters `beforeskip`, `afterskip`, `innerskip`

However, using these, I haven't been able to get rid of the additional space on the *part* pages that's not present on my title page.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

```latex
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{setspace}

% MODIFY APPEARANCE OF PART PAGES
\renewcommand\partformat{%
    \fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\selectfont%
    \partname~\thepart%
}

\setkomafont{part}{\fontsize{24pt}{34pt}\selectfont}

\renewcommand\partlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        % HEADLINE
        \node[rectangle, anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt, text width=130mm, text=white] (headline) at ($(current page.south west) + (16mm, 72mm)$) {#3};

        % SUBHEADLINE
        \node[rectangle, anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt, text width=130mm, text=white] (subheadline) at ($(headline.north west) + (0, 16mm)$) {#2};

         % BACKGROUND
        \fill[lightgray] ($(current page.north west) + (8mm, -38mm)$) rectangle ($(current page.east |- subheadline.north) + (0, 16mm)$);

        % TEXTBOX
        \fill[gray, fill opacity=0.9] ($(current page.west |- subheadline.north) + (0mm, 32mm)$) rectangle ($(current page.west |- headline.south) + (154mm, -16mm)$);

        % HEADLINE
        \node[rectangle, anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt, text width=130mm, text=white, draw] at (headline.south west) {#3};

        % SUBHEADLINE
        \node[rectangle, anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt, text width=130mm, text=white, draw] at (subheadline.south west) {#2};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{document}
\sffamily
\onehalfspacing

% TITLE PAGE
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        % BACKGROUND
        \fill[lightgray] ($(current page.north west) + (8mm, -38mm)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east)$);

        % HEADLINE
        \node[rectangle, anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt, text width=130mm, text=white] (headline) at ($(current page.south west) + (16mm, 32mm)$) {\fontsize{24pt}{34pt}\selectfont \sffamily\bfseries Quantitative Foundations of \\ Artificial Intelligence \par};

        % SUBHEADLINE
        \node[rectangle, anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt, text width=130mm, text=white] (subheadline) at ($(headline.north west) + (0, 8mm)$) {\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\selectfont \sffamily\bfseries Name of University \textbar{} Winter 2023/24 \par};

        % TEXTBOX
        \fill[gray, fill opacity=0.9] ($(current page.west |- subheadline.north) + (0mm, 16mm)$) rectangle ($(current page.south west) + (154mm, 16mm)$);

        % HEADLINE
        \node[rectangle, anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt, text width=130mm, text=white, draw] at (headline.south west) {\fontsize{24pt}{34pt}\selectfont \bfseries Quantitative Foundations of \\ Artificial Intelligence \par};

        % SUBHEADLINE
        \node[rectangle, anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt, text width=130mm, text=white, draw] at (subheadline.south west) {\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\selectfont \bfseries Name of University \textbar{} Winter 2023/24 \par};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{titlepage}

\part{Quantitative Foundations of Artificial Intelligence}
\part{Quantitative Foundations}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: It isn't your Ti*k*Z code. It's something in `#3` i.e. something the class is doing to format the title of the `\part` before it is passed to the `tikzpicture` code. In general, I would advise against using the Koma classes when you want to implement a highly specific, customised format. It is easier to start with one of the standard classes and create a custom style. As it is, you are basically going to be fighting Koma all the way. (I'm guessing this isn't the last document element you'll need to impose rigid requirements on.) Note also you aren't getting exactly the font sizes you request.

Comment: Hi @cfr! Thanks for pointing this out! Yes, I am aware of the fact that this has nothing to do with TikZ and everything to do with the #3 argument of the `\partlineswithprefixformat` command. I should've pointed that out in my original post, excuse me. As far as having to fight KOMA all the way, this is actually the last element that needed placement. That's why I was looking for some way to fix this single problem instead of having to change everything else. Thank you very much for your feedback!

Comment: Very nice question with excellent MWE! BTW: I disagree with cfr. Often it is easier to use KOMA-Script to define a highly specific, customized format than using a standard class and loading lots of packages or doing a lot of low-level coding. There also several examples on CTAN for such CI classes and packages using KOMA-Script, e.g., [tuda-ci](https://ctan.org/pkg/tuda-ci). See also the last example in my answer to see, how easy it could be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the same formatting for the title page and the part titles, I would suggest to use the same code for both:

```latex
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{setspace}

% MODIFY APPEARANCE OF PART PAGES
\renewcommand\partformat{%
    \partname~\thepart%
}

% You can do the font selection in the TikZ code below,
% and then either don't change the fontsize here (or
% use \normalsize) would be enough.
\setkomafont{part}{}
\setkomafont{partnumber}{}
% You also do all the distances in the TikZ code, so
% not adding additional distances by the part heading itself
% would be suggested.
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt,innerskip=0pt,afterskip=0pt]{part}

\newcommand{\TikZTitle}[2]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        % BACKGROUND
        \fill[lightgray] ($(current page.north west) + (8mm, -38mm)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east)$);

        % HEADLINE
        \node[rectangle, anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt, text width=130mm, text=white] (headline) at ($(current page.south west) + (16mm, 32mm)$) {\fontsize{24pt}{34pt}\let\strut\relax\sffamily\bfseries #2\par};

        % SUBHEADLINE
        \node[rectangle, anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt, text width=130mm, text=white] (subheadline) at ($(headline.north west) + (0, 8mm)$) {\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\sffamily\bfseries #1\par};

        % TEXTBOX
        \fill[gray, fill opacity=0.9] ($(current page.west |- subheadline.north) + (0mm, 16mm)$) rectangle ($(current page.south west) + (154mm, 16mm)$);

        % HEADLINE
        \node[rectangle, anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt, text width=130mm, text=white, draw] at (headline.south west) {\fontsize{24pt}{34pt}\bfseries\let\strut\relax #2\par};

        % SUBHEADLINE
        \node[rectangle, anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt, text width=130mm, text=white, draw] at (subheadline.south west) {\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\bfseries #1\par};
   \end{tikzpicture}
}

\renewcommand\partlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \TikZTitle{#2}{#3}%
}


\begin{document}
\sffamily
\onehalfspacing

% TITLE PAGE
\begin{titlepage}
  \TikZTitle{Name of University \textbar{} Winter 2023/24}
            {Quantitative Foundations of \\ Artificial Intelligence }
\end{titlepage}

\part[{Quantitative Foundations of Artificial Intelligence}]{Quantitative Foundations of \\ Artificial Intelligence}
\part{Quantitative Foundations}

\end{document}
```

Here are the results only the odd pages:

[image: example without strut]

I've added `\let\strut\relax` to this solution, because KOMA-Script always adds a `\strut` to the end of the text of the part heading, to have the same height and depth of, e.g., “ace” and “ACÉ (generic)”, but it seems, you don't want this. But if you want, you can alternatively remove the `\let\strut\relax` and add a `\strut` and the end of the arguments at your title page:

```latex
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{setspace}

% MODIFY APPEARANCE OF PART PAGES
\renewcommand\partformat{%
    \partname~\thepart%
}

% You can do the font selection in the TikZ code below,
% and then either don't change the fontsize here (or
% use \normalsize) would be enough.
\setkomafont{part}{}
\setkomafont{partnumber}{}
% You also do all the distances in the TikZ code, so
% not adding additional distances by the part heading itself
% would be suggested.
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt,innerskip=0pt,afterskip=0pt]{part}

\newcommand{\TikZTitle}[2]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        % BACKGROUND
        \fill[lightgray] ($(current page.north west) + (8mm, -38mm)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east)$);

        % HEADLINE
        \node[rectangle, anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt, text width=130mm, text=white] (headline) at ($(current page.south west) + (16mm, 32mm)$) {\fontsize{24pt}{34pt}\sffamily\bfseries #2\par};

        % SUBHEADLINE
        \node[rectangle, anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt, text width=130mm, text=white] (subheadline) at ($(headline.north west) + (0, 8mm)$) {\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\sffamily\bfseries #1\par};

        % TEXTBOX
        \fill[gray, fill opacity=0.9] ($(current page.west |- subheadline.north) + (0mm, 16mm)$) rectangle ($(current page.south west) + (154mm, 16mm)$);

        % HEADLINE
        \node[rectangle, anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt, text width=130mm, text=white, draw] at (headline.south west) {\fontsize{24pt}{34pt}\bfseries #2\par};

        % SUBHEADLINE
        \node[rectangle, anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt, text width=130mm, text=white, draw] at (subheadline.south west) {\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\bfseries #1\par};
   \end{tikzpicture}
}

\renewcommand\partlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \TikZTitle{#2}{#3}%
}


\begin{document}
\sffamily
\onehalfspacing

% TITLE PAGE
\begin{titlepage}
  \TikZTitle{Name of University \textbar{} Winter 2023/24}
            {Quantitative Foundations of \\ Artificial Intelligence\strut}
\end{titlepage}

\part[{Quantitative Foundations of Artificial Intelligence}]
{Quantitative Foundations of \\ Artificial Intelligence}
\part{Quantitative Foundations}

\end{document}
```

[image: with strut]

In both cases the only differences between the title page and the part pages are the height and depth of the subtitle, because of a `y`, `|`, and `/` in the subtitle of the title page. To avoid this difference, you can add `\strut` to the usage of the subtitle:

```latex
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{setspace}

% MODIFY APPEARANCE OF PART PAGES
\renewcommand\partformat{%
    \partname~\thepart%
}

% You can do the font selection in the TikZ code below,
% and then either don't change the fontsize here (or
% use \normalsize) would be enough.
\setkomafont{part}{}
\setkomafont{partnumber}{}
% You also do all the distances in the TikZ code, so
% not adding additional distances by the part heading itself
% would be suggested.
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt,innerskip=0pt,afterskip=0pt]{part}

\newcommand{\TikZTitle}[2]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        % BACKGROUND
        \fill[lightgray] ($(current page.north west) + (8mm, -38mm)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east)$);

        % HEADLINE
        \node[rectangle, anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt, text width=130mm, text=white] (headline) at ($(current page.south west) + (16mm, 32mm)$) {\fontsize{24pt}{34pt}\sffamily\bfseries #2\par};

        % SUBHEADLINE
        \node[rectangle, anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt, text width=130mm, text=white] (subheadline) at ($(headline.north west) + (0, 8mm)$) {\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\sffamily\bfseries\strut #1\par};

        % TEXTBOX
        \fill[gray, fill opacity=0.9] ($(current page.west |- subheadline.north) + (0mm, 16mm)$) rectangle ($(current page.south west) + (154mm, 16mm)$);

        % HEADLINE
        \node[rectangle, anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt, text width=130mm, text=white, draw] at (headline.south west) {\fontsize{24pt}{34pt}\bfseries #2\par};

        % SUBHEADLINE
        \node[rectangle, anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt, text width=130mm, text=white, draw] at (subheadline.south west) {\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\bfseries\strut #1\par};
   \end{tikzpicture}
}

\renewcommand\partlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \TikZTitle{#2}{#3}%
}


\begin{document}
\sffamily
\onehalfspacing

% TITLE PAGE
\begin{titlepage}
  \TikZTitle{Name of University \textbar{} Winter 2023/24}
            {Quantitative Foundations of \\ Artificial Intelligence\strut}
\end{titlepage}

\part[{Quantitative Foundations of Artificial Intelligence}]
{Quantitative Foundations of \\ Artificial Intelligence}
\part{Quantitative Foundations}

\end{document}
```

[image: with extra strut for the subtitle]

BTW: Theoretically KOMA-Script would also support to define a completely new sectioning style. Unfortunately currently there isn't an official documentation of this feature, maybe because currently it needs to define an internal command:

```latex
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{setspace}

% MODIFY APPEARANCE OF PART PAGES
\renewcommand\partformat{%
    \partname~\thepart%
}

\newcommand{\TikZTitle}[2]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        % BACKGROUND
        \fill[lightgray] ($(current page.north west) + (8mm, -38mm)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east)$);

        % HEADLINE
        \node[rectangle, anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt, text width=130mm, text=white] (headline) at ($(current page.south west) + (16mm, 32mm)$) {\fontsize{24pt}{34pt}\sffamily\bfseries #2\par};

        % SUBHEADLINE
        \node[rectangle, anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt, text width=130mm,
        text=white] (subheadline) at ($(headline.north west) + (0, 8mm)$)
        {\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\sffamily\bfseries #1\par};

        % TEXTBOX
        \fill[gray, fill opacity=0.9] ($(current page.west |- subheadline.north) + (0mm, 16mm)$) rectangle ($(current page.south west) + (154mm, 16mm)$);

        % HEADLINE
        \node[rectangle, anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt, text width=130mm, text=white, draw] at (headline.south west) {\fontsize{24pt}{34pt}\bfseries #2\par};

        % SUBHEADLINE
        \node[rectangle, anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt, text width=130mm, text=white, draw] at (subheadline.south west) {\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\bfseries #1\par};
   \end{tikzpicture}
}

\makeatletter
% This is used to set the style tikzpart of a command. The argument is the
% name of the command as used for \DeclareSectionCommand etc.
\newcommand*{\scr@dsc@def@style@tikzpart@command}[1]{%
  \@namedef{#1}{\dotikzpart{#1}}%
}
% This makes a new heading of type tikzpart. The aruments are:
% #1: The name of the command (see \scr@dsc@def@style@tikzpart@command)
% #2: star or not (star is used for not numbered headings)
% #3: ToC entry (currently only used for numbered headings)
% #4: title
\NewDocumentCommand\dotikzpart{m s O{#4} m}
  {
    \cleardoubleoddpage\thispagestyle{empty}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#2}{%
      \TikZTitle{}{#4}%
    }{%
      \refstepcounter{#1}%
      \@nameuse{add#1tocentry}{\@nameuse{the#1}}{#3}%
      \TikZTitle{\csname #1format\endcsname}{#4}%
    }%
    \clearpage
  }
\makeatother
\RedeclareSectionCommand[style=tikzpart]{part}% use the new style for \part 

\begin{document}
\sffamily
\onehalfspacing

\tableofcontents

% TITLE PAGE
\begin{titlepage}
  \TikZTitle{Name of University \textbar{} Winter 2023/24}
            {Quantitative Foundations of \\ Artificial Intelligence}
\end{titlepage}

\part[{Quantitative Foundations of Artificial Intelligence}]
{Quantitative Foundations of \\ Artificial Intelligence}
\part{Quantitative Foundations}

\end{document}
```

Note: This is a very rudimentary example. For example it does not support the extended optional argument of the original KOMA-Script `\part`. However, it shows, that definition of new sectioning styles could be very easy.

Comment: This works like a charm, thank you very much! As far as the placement of the rectangles in the background goes, they were indeed intended to be different (i.e., title page vs. part pages). I have adjusted your code to account for this, and the result is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @ma_thss Note that you could avoid the need to duplicate nodes by using the `backgrounds` library and putting the background shapes `on background layer`.

Comment: @cfr Awesome, thanks for pointing this out! I expected there to be a nicer solution than just duplicating the nodes, thank you very much for pointing me to the solution!